# Get a tag code in html with regular expression

Tags: java, html, regex, string

I want to get every tag like below (every tag code within `<>`, inclusively) in a html document. I've tried with `/<.+>/`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<table class="body wrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="width: 100%;max-width: 600px;background-color: #f4f4f4;">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean every tag like below? What part of the tag should be included in the ones that match?

Comment: get the whole <table> tag(in this case) and every other tag out of a large html document.

Comment: Try `/<[^<>]+>/` or better `/<.+?>/`

Comment: @frank Do you want to include the end tags aswell?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class HTMLTagMatcher
{
  private static final String REGEX = "<[^\\/][^<>]+>";
  private static final String INPUT = "<test><blah /><test2></test><best><blargh></best><outside>";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher match = p.matcher(INPUT);
    while (match.find()) {
      System.out.println(match.group());
    }
  }
}
```